# How to style a css on the head tag using slim-rails gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, slim-lang

I'm using the `gem "slim-rails"` and I need to put on the file `application.html.slim` inside the `head` tag a style css like this:

```
<style>
    <% State.all.each do |state| %>
      .state-<%= state.name.parameterize %> {
        background-color: <%= state.color %>;
      }
    <% end %>
</style>
```

I was trying in this way:

```
  style
      - State.all.each do |state|
        .state-
          = "#{state.name.parameterize}" {
              background-color: = "#{state.color}";
            }
```

But was unsuccessfully. the error:

```
Malformed indentation
  /Users/romenigld/ror_workspace/projects/news_city/app/views/layouts/application.html.slim, Line 20, Column 12
    }
    ^
```

It has a way for this using helpers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix putting on the partial of the `views/states/_state.html.slim` this:

```
span class="label state state-#{state.name.parameterize}" style="background-color: #{state.color};"
  = "#{state}"
```